# How to use a function to transform axis values with ggplot2?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, arithmetic-expressions

**Instead of 'log2', I want to use 'log2/(log2-1)'**

```
sp <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
sp
sp + scale_x_continuous(trans='log2') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log2')
```

**When I try, I get:**

```
object 'log2/(log2-1)_trans' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: It works for me. Trying reestarting R or rerun `library(ggplot2)`,

Comment: Not working for me. Can you show your result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the function first, and its inverse for the labelling, then use the `trans_new` function from the scales package:

```
log2_1 <- function(x) log2(x)/(log2(x)-1)
antilog2_1 <- function(x) 2^(x/(x-1))

sp + scale_x_continuous(trans = trans_new("log2_1", 
                                          transform=log2_1,
                                          inverse=antilog2_1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = trans_new("log2_1", 
                                       transform=log2_1,
                                       inverse=antilog2_1))
```

---

[image]