How to plot a ternary with absolute values while retaining equal spacing using ggtern in R
I'm trying to generate a ternary plot with contour inside, my variable conc1, conc2, conc3 in term of ZIP, but I want to plot the absolute on the sides of the triangle, however, my code plot these values in uneven spacing:

I want to plot something similar this while keeping the absolute values.
This my data structure:
tibble [125 × 14] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ block_id     : num [1:125] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ conc1        : num [1:125] 0 0.3 0.15 0.075 0.0375 0 0.3 0.15 0.075 0.0375 ...
 $ conc2        : num [1:125] 0 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 ...
 $ conc3        : num [1:125] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ZIP_fit      : num [1:125] 2.03 93.37 90.1 77.32 72.86 ...
 $ ZIP_ref      : num [1:125] 2.03 89.87 69.93 52.5 43.38 ...
 $ ZIP_synergy  : num [1:125] 0 3.5 20.2 24.8 29.5 ...
 $ HSA_ref      : num [1:125] 2.03 85.48 51.92 38.55 40.02 ...
 $ HSA_synergy  : num [1:125] 0 6.99 40.32 38.11 34.54 ...
 $ Loewe_ref    : num [1:125] 2.03 84.81 53.22 35.13 20.92 ...
 $ Loewe_synergy: num [1:125] 0 7.66 39.02 41.53 53.64 ...
 $ Loewe_ci     : num [1:125] NA 0.658 0.349 0.306 0.161 ...
 $ Bliss_ref    : num [1:125] 2.03 91.22 70.65 56.03 46.33 ...
 $ Bliss_synergy: num [1:125] 0 1.26 21.59 20.64 28.23 ...

this is my data (head part):
# A tibble: 6 × 14
  block_id  conc1 conc2 conc3 ZIP_fit ZIP_ref ZIP_synergy HSA_ref HSA_synergy
     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1        1 0       0        0    2.03    2.03        0       2.03        0   
2        1 0.3     0.05     0   93.4    89.9         3.50   85.5         6.99
3        1 0.15    0.05     0   90.1    69.9        20.2    51.9        40.3 
4        1 0.075   0.05     0   77.3    52.5        24.8    38.6        38.1 
5        1 0.0375  0.05     0   72.9    43.4        29.5    40.0        34.5 
6        1 0       0.05     0   38.6    38.6         0      38.6         0   
# ℹ 5 more variables: Loewe_ref <dbl>, Loewe_synergy <dbl>, Loewe_ci <dbl>,
#   Bliss_ref <dbl>, Bliss_synergy <dbl>


this is my code:
library(ggtern)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

conc1_values <- c(0, 0.3, 0.15, 0.075, 0.0375)
conc2_values <- c(0, 0.05, 0.025, 0.0125, 0.00625)
conc3_values <- c(0, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125)

eff_data <- read_xlsx("/Users/triple.xlsx")

head(eff_data) 
str(eff_data) 

expanded_data <- expand.grid(conc1 = conc1_values, conc2 = conc2_values, conc3 = conc3_values)


eff_data <- merge(expanded_data, eff_data, by = c("conc1", "conc2", "conc3"))

ggtern(data = eff_data, mapping = aes(x = conc1, y = conc2, z = conc3)) +
  stat_density_tern(geom = 'polygon', n = 400, bdl = 0.01, 
                    aes(fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "", 
                      breaks = 1:5, labels = c("low", "", "", "", "high")) +
  
  scale_L_continuous(breaks = conc1_values, labels = round(conc1_values, 4)) +
  scale_R_continuous(breaks = conc2_values, labels = round(conc2_values, 4)) +
  scale_T_continuous(breaks = conc3_values, labels = round(conc3_values, 4)) +
  labs(title = "Density plot") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(order = 2), alpha = guide_none()) +
  theme_rgbg() +
  theme_noarrows() +
  theme(legend.justification = c(0, 1), legend.position = c(0, 1))

I want to generate a figure like this:

or something like this:


I don't understand. You want even spacing between uneven breaks?

Of course I want even breaks.

The values you are plotting are not evenly spaced, but it sounds like you want them to appear as if they were evenly spaced? Sorry, there's something I'm misunderstanding. When you say "my code plot these values in uneven spacing," what specifically are you referring to, and how would you like those values to appear?

Thank you for asking! Yes, exactly, they are not evenly spaced, and I want them to be evenly spaced.

To take conc3_values as an example, you specify five values that are not evenly spaced. You could use conc3_values = seq(0, 1, 0.25) if you wanted evenly spaced breaks. But presumably you specified your breaks intentionally?

Each one has 5 values, I mean the conc. I was trying to break the sides of the triangle into even breaks, for instance: hypothetically conc3 values are 0-5, there will 1, 2, 3 values equally spaced on the side. Instead of the hypothetical values, I want my values to be equally spaced on each side.

@JonSpring I've updated my question with the figure shape that I want to plot.

There is "limits= " option as part of scale_continuous  function.  From your question it is not clear what your desired limits are.  Be warned, one can't arbitrary set the axis in a ternary plot, they must form a equilateral triangle.

It is possible to do what you want by transforming the variables and reverse-transforming the breaks. However, I'm not sure if plotting your data in a ternary plot even makes sense. In a ternary plot, the three variables must always sum to the same value, but you are plotting raw concentrations for which the sums may vary. A ternary plot can't be used to plot three independent variables, which your set-up seems to imply. Can you clarify please?

It sounds like you have a situation where your mixtures follow an equation like Asqrt(a) + Bsqrt(b) + C*sqrt(c) = 1. As Allan notes, you could apply a custom transformation to get that spacing and labeling, by specifying each transformation (and its reverse for the labels). Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60901849/6851825

@AllanCameron thank you for your comment, I see, you are right, my variables are independent and not equal, when I looked to plot four variables, I found only ggtern and [this package] (https://ptarroso.github.io/Triplot/) but I wasn't successful. How can this be done by transformation if variables are not equal? because it can be done with two variables in term of third variable in synergyfinder package (I'm referring to the synergy graph).

@Adam my point is that I don't think the data you have just isn't suitable for a ternary plot, however it is transformed. Can you explain why you want to display it as a ternary plot as opposed to say a faceted 2D density plot of conc1 versus conc2 at each of the 5 values of conc3?

The data in a ternary plot is necessarily dependent: there are only two degrees of freedom describing position on a 2d surface, but this is consistent with three components if and only if they add to 1, ie any variable is determined by the other two. If that relationship doesn't hold, then it's unclear how a point could be mapped to a single position.

@AllanCameron It wasn't my intention to use ternary plot. I want to do faceted 2D density plot in triangle shape, which would make more sense. The ZIP score in my data is dependent on the combination of two (assuming the third is zero) or three variables (conc), so I need to plot a density or contour shows which combination result in high or low ZIP score. I also tried to scale the data, but since the conc have zero value, it wasn't feasible to standard deviate zero values.

@JonSpring the ZIP score is depended in the combination of the conc variables.

I understand ZIP may be defined by the conc variables, but if conc1 is X and conc2 is Y, do you know for a fact what conc3 is? If not, a ternary plot won't work here. If so, this should be possible.

@JonSpring yes, all variables have their values, they are known. You can revisit the data structure in the post.

I mean if you didn't have conc3, could you determine it from conc1 and conc2? Could each concentration be specified as a function of the other two?

@JonSpring I see what you mean, all conc are correlated to ZIP, conc1 alone or conc3 alone can be plotted in term of ZIP as the other two conc values are zeros. However; conc variables are independent of each other, they are not function of each other without ZIP as a function.
